# Conditional formatting when checkbox checked

Tags: numbers

I am trying to make conditional highlighting accross whole row when a checkbox is checked. I found a [tutorial](https://macmost.com/use-conditional-highlighting-across-a-whole-row-in-numbers.html) to make this happen, but it doesn't work for me. If you know a better way to do this, please show me how.

At this moment I am trying to use formula from the tutorial:

[image]

Where A3 is the checkbox. When I check/uncheck the checkbox  I see in the bottom statusbar TRUE/FALSE state, but the formula is not working. In the example it's always showing "NOT YO".

Answer (score 0):

If I think what your asking is what I think might work have you selected from the bottom of what you want to the top?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `IF($A3; "YO"; "NOT YO")`.

IF uses the first result if the condition is true. A checkbox is true or false, never equal to the string "TRUE" in letters. You could also compare to true — you'll know if it's the right true value as Numbers will show it as a grey token.